# How to pass all the form values to a validate funtion in formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik

I am trying to validate several inputs according to each other. so I need to pass current form values to validate function. Is there anyway to do so in formik.

for more insight, I declared all my inputs as object in file like below

```
 postal_code: {
name: "postal_code",
validate: (value) => {
  return postalCodeValidator(value, {
    required: false,
  });
},
inputProps: {
  seperator: "-",
  seperationCount: 5,
  length: 10,
  placeholder: "12121212",
},
}
```

and render it in another component as follow

```
<>
  <div validationref={field.name}></div>
  {React.cloneElement(props.children, {
    onChange: (e) =>
      setFieldValue(
        field.name,
        props.field.isHtmlInput ? e.target.value : e
      ),
    name: field.name,
    value: field.value,
  })}
  {meta.error ? <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{meta.error}</div> : null}
</>
```

please let me know if any extra information is needed
I would appreciate any hint

Comment: you should has access to `formikBag` property or `values`

Comment: the validate function only accepts one parameter which is the value of the input. not whole form

Comment: then u need to pass all values to that function or make validation on form level. And it's a good practice to validate form instead of field when u have dependence on other form values.